# Google script - how to check the value of a drop down box and then update another drop down from that

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am very new to writing scripts in google sheets and so would appreciate any help please. Also, if anyone has any links to some good programs to learn to program scripts I would be very grateful too! Thank you in advance.

I have written the following code:

```js
function updateDQcall() {
  
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var salesSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sales Tracker");
  var duringCall = "Yes";
  var beforeCall = "N/A";
  var canLead = "Cancelled - by Lead";
  var canRep = "Cancelled - by Rep";
  var notDQ = null;
  
  
  var r = salesSheet.getActiveCell();

  if (r.getColumn()== 13) {

    var row = r.getRow();


    if (r.getValue() == 'No') {
          salesSheet.getRange(row, 15).setValue(null);
        } else if (r.getValue() == 'Yes - During Call') { 
          salesSheet.getRange(row, 15).setValue(duringCall);
        } else if (r.getValue() === '') {
          salesSheet.getrange(row, 15).setValue(null);
        } else if (r.getValue() == 'Yes - Before Call') {
          salesSheet.getRange(row, 15).setValue(beforeCall);
        } else if (r.getValue() == 'Yes - Other') {
          salesSheet.getRange(row, 15).setValue(null);
        } 

  }
}
```

I am looking at column 13 (data starts on row 3) which is a drop down box with a few options in it. Depending on what option is selected I want the drop down box in column 15 to then update to one of its options. I cannot though for the life of me get the option to work where if you delete the dropdown value out of column 13 it then blanks out the dropdown value in column 15.

Can anyone help? Also, this spread sheet could end up getting quite long so would this code be the most efficient way that I could write it?

I am really grateful to anyone who answers thank you for your time.

Nick

Comment: Please explain and clarify "get the option to work where if you delete the dropdown value out of column 13 it then blanks out the dropdown value in column 15" . What is you goal ?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear on this Aerials. So I have a drop down box in column 13 and a different drop down box in column 15. If the user deletes / clears the option selected out of the dropdown box in column 13 I would like the code to then delete / clear the option that populated in dropdown box in column 15.

I used this: else if (r.getValue() === '') {
          salesSheet.getrange(row, 15).setValue(null);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function updateDQcall() {
  
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var salesSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sales Tracker");
  var map = {
    'No': '',
    'Yes - During Call': 'Yes',
    '': '',
    'Yes - Before Call': 'N/A',
    'Yes - Other': ''
  };
/*
  var duringCall = "Yes";
  var beforeCall = "N/A";
  var canLead = "Cancelled - by Lead";
  var canRep = "Cancelled - by Rep";
  var notDQ = null;
*/  
  
  var r = salesSheet.getActiveCell();

  if (r.getColumn()== 13) {

    var row = r.getRow();

    salesSheet.getRange(row, 15).setValue(map[r.getValue()]);
/*
    if (r.getValue() == 'No') {
          salesSheet.getRange(row, 15).setValue(null);
        } else if (r.getValue() == 'Yes - During Call') { 
          salesSheet.getRange(row, 15).setValue(duringCall);
        } else if (r.getValue() === '') {
          salesSheet.getrange(row, 15).setValue(null);
        } else if (r.getValue() == 'Yes - Before Call') {
          salesSheet.getRange(row, 15).setValue(beforeCall);
        } else if (r.getValue() == 'Yes - Other') {
          salesSheet.getRange(row, 15).setValue(null);
        } 
*/
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much idfurw that worked perfectly and you made is so much simpler than my way of trying! I am going to break down what you have written and learn about the elements that make it up so I know better for next time. Can't thank you enough - kind regards, Nick.